# Sql query + wpml in one language only

Tags: mysql, query, phpmyadmin, wordpress

I'm not a developer, just a normal user, so please don't expect me to be like you :)

I'm managing my website in WordPress, Running 4 languages using WPML, (en,de,cz,pl)
My concern is, I want to search and replace text in posts but only in one specific language not all languages.

For examplex: I want to search for word "Hello" in posts in German language only and replace it with "Hallo".and keep "Hello" as it is without any changes in Czech and Polish posts.
WPML has translation table in Mysql DB in a different way, I'm not a techie guy, just a mature and geek..
Any one can help with this query please?
Thank you

Comment: Try https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How do you identify a post as being "German"?  Or do you want to blindly change all `Hallo` to `Hello`?

Comment: No particular thing to identify posts by language, WPML sort it somehow I don't know. I don't mean to change "Hello" to "Hallo" in blind way, it will replace the word in all posts, I want to replace in German posts only.. As translation table exists in database